# Active admin passing params after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

As a Rails novice, I have been struggling with an Activeadmin problem for a couple of days now, and I just cannot figure out how to solve it.

For various reasons it is necessary for me to build an object when showing a form for a new Invoice object.  I have the route

```
“admin/orders/:order_id/invoices/new" => "admin/invoices#new"
```

and need to build the order object when the Invoice form is displayed.  Before anyone points out that ActiveAdmin can do this by setting the ActiveAdmin has_many, yes I know this is the case but given the model structure I have, this is not suitable for this app (among other things, not all Invoices will have a linked order).

So, I set an after_initialize on my Invoice model, like this:

```
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
   @ordergroup = Ordergroup.new
   @ordergroup.order = Order.find(@options[:order_id]) 
   self.ordergroup << @ordergroup
  end
```

Simples.  Only problem is passing the order_id in the params to the model.  I have been experimenting with a range of initialize functions, but whatever I do seems to lead to complete disaster.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  If this wasn’t Activeadmin, and I was calling the new Invoice directly, I could do Invoice.new(params), but with Activeadmin this seems to be called automatically as part of the form functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by total disaster? I don't know active_admin too well, but it might help figuring out what's going wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `after_initialize` rather than `before_save` or `before_validation`? ActiveAdmin is probably creating a new empty Order to help it build the forms and such.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  In development, anything that doesn't work I consider a total disaster...  I have tried about a million different things, with about the same amount of different errors.  Latest attempt is

`  
  def initialize(*params)
    super
    @linked_order_id = params(:order_id)
  end
`

which just returns "Couldn't find Order without an ID" on the after_initialize `@ordergroup.order = Order.find(@linked_order_id)`

Comment: @muistooshort I need to build the object before the form is rendered to show the linked order in the form part 
`  
     f.has_many :ordergroup do |og|
        og.input :order
      end      
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it would seem, is simply to skip all the after_initialize and initialize hassle and rewrite the new method in Activeadmin

```
admin/invoice.rb

def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  if params[:order_id]
    @invoice.linknew(params[:order_id])
  end
end
```

.

```
invoice.rb

  def linknew(order_id = {})
    @order_id = order_id
    @ordergroup = Ordergroup.new
    @ordergroup.order = Order.find(@order_id)
    self.ordergroup << @ordergroup
  end
```

Two days it took me to figure that one out...